# Проблема с библиотекой filterpy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Пытаюсь выполнить пример из книги "Kalman_and_Bayesian_Filters_in_Python" на странице 17. Код пишу в jupyter в веб-браузере. Но мне выдает ошибку:

> No module named 'gh_internal'.

Как этот модуль подключить? В Pycharm вроде библиотеку filterpy установил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"В Pycharm вроде библиотеку filterpy установил"* -- вы уверены, что jupyter использует то же python окружение что и PyCharm? Здесь хорошо бы канонический вопрос/ответ написать о *"Я установил модуль X в окружении Y, а он не импортируется в Z"*, можно было бы как дубликат закрыть.